NetSuite SOAP `searchMoreWithId` API only returns first page if returnSearchColumns == true
I use the NetSuite SOAP API to retrieve a saved search. Specifically, I am using the search API and, when the search results exceed the 1000-row page size, the searchMoreWithId API. This works when I supply <returnSearchColumns>false</returnSearchColumns> initial search call. For example, one of our searches correctly returns 3383 rows (over 4 pages).
However, when I supply <returnSearchColumns>true</returnSearchColumns> in the initial search call, each call to searchMoreWithId for the next page just keeps returning the first page. With the same search above, I get back a total of 4000 rows — the first 1000 records duplicated 4 times. In other words, all the pages are just the first page.
I've even recreated this in Postman, supplying each pageIndex value and confirming the results are the same 1000 rows.
This tells me that that pagination doesn’t work with the searchMoreWithId API when <returnSearchColumns>false</returnSearchColumns> is supplied in the original search call. Am I missing something or is there some sort of bug in this API?
Edit:
Including code snippet per comment (we're in a Node env). That said, as mentioned above, I've recreated this issue in Postman as well, supplying subsequent pageIndex values and confirming that I get the same 1000 rows for each page.
const totalPages = searchResult.totalPages;
for (let pageToFetch = searchResult.pageIndex + 1; pageToFetch <= totalPages; pageToFetch++) {
  const searchMoreWithIdResult = await this.netSuiteClient.getSearchMoreWithId(
    searchResult.searchId,
    pageToFetch,
    // when this is true, same page is returned every time
    returnSearchColumns, 
  );

  const searchMoreWithIdRows = (searchMoreWithIdResult.searchRowList?.searchRow ?? []).concat(
    searchResult.recordList?.record ?? [],
  );
  searchRows.push(...searchMoreWithIdRows);
}


If this doesn't help then please show your code.
How I've used this API with Java and the AXIS client is like:
while(result != null){ // with the previous result
   if(result.getSearchId() != null) result = getPort(false).searchMoreWithId(result.getSearchId(), result.getPageIndex() + 1);
 //process results
}


Thanks for the response! I updated my question with a code snippet.
